# What will be the output of if I use following statement in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select customer_name from customer like %null%
```

Comment: Syntax error...

Comment: try it! it is more fun to test it on your own.

Comment: That's not a valid SQL statement in Oracle.

Comment: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error, like clause must be like this :

```
Select customer_name from customer WHERE like '%null%'
```

Here you check if string (varchar column) like null =>

if customer column contain "todonulltoto", like return row.

But in this case, you can use (if check null value)

```
Select customer_name from customer WHERE customer_name  IS NULL;
```

Comment: Your proposed code (last line) will also throw a syntax error: WHERE can't immediately follow FROM (without saying from what table you are selecting).

Comment: So will the first one, where *what* is like that string?

Comment: Yes, sorry, copy/past problem haha